# How to add duplicated values in a matrix in R

Tags: r

Starting from this sample matrix:

```
 my.matrix <- cbind(c('a','b','c','a','d','a','e','f','g','h','a'), c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4))
 my.matrix
         [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "1" 
 [2,] "b"  "1" 
 [3,] "c"  "1" 
 [4,] "a"  "1" 
 [5,] "d"  "2" 
 [6,] "a"  "2" 
 [7,] "e"  "2" 
 [8,] "f"  "2" 
 [9,] "g"  "3" 
 [10,] "h"  "4" 
 [11,] "a"  "4"
```

Is there a way of adding the numerical values of every repeated letter? so that the final result would be:

```
cbind(c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'), c(7,1,1,2,2,2,3,4))
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "7" 
[2,] "b"  "1" 
[3,] "c"  "1" 
[4,] "d"  "2" 
[5,] "e"  "2" 
[6,] "f"  "2" 
[7,] "g"  "3" 
[8,] "h"  "4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having data of mixed types in a matrix is not a good idea. It would be easier to store things in a data.frame then you could use `aggregate` to collapse and summarize data

```
my.data <- data.frame(
     a=c('a','b','c','a','d','a','e','f','g','h','a'),
     b=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4)
)

aggregate(b~a, my.data, sum)
```

which returns

```
  a b
1 a 8
2 b 1
3 c 1
4 d 2
5 e 2
6 f 2
7 g 3
8 h 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tapply`:

```
> tapply(as.numeric(my.matrix[, 2]), my.matrix[, 1], sum)
a b c d e f g h 
8 1 1 2 2 2 3 4
```

Note in this case it may make more sense to use a data frame instead of a matrix since the columns are different types.  Also, your sample answer appears to be wrong.

If you really want a matrix as the result you can `cbind` the names of the result above with the values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other great answers using base R, you could consider an approach using the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

# Use a data frame rather than a matrix
my.data <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'a'),
                      y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4))

my.data %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarize(count = sum(y))

#   x count
# 1 a     8
# 2 b     1
# 3 c     1
# 4 d     2
# 5 e     2
# 6 f     2
# 7 g     3
# 8 h     4
```

Note that as Mr. Flick said, you should use a data frame rather than a matrix when you have mixed data types.